# UITableView & Controller gives me empty table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an application (Navigation Controller) in which the second controller is a Table View Controller. I am able to send my required data through the segue, but unable to update the entries in the tableview programmatically.

I'm new to IOS.

This is my header file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface HCIResultListViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *resultList;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableListView;

@end
```

This is my implementation file.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HelloCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";

// Configure the cell...

return cell;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to work with tableview & Controllers?

I did go through several documentation and examples but really couldnt understand

Comment: `numberOfRowsInSection` & `numberOfSectionsInTableView` returns 0 number

Comment: Extremely sorry for this question!. Just a small overlook!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the rows and section count for the table view. like this.

```
  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
    #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [sourceData Count]//i.e., 10;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HelloCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What would you expect in your `UITableView` if you set the `numberOfRowsInSection`  to 0?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return 0; // it should be size of your Array or List 
}
```

You should change the number of rows to the Array size or whatever data you are populating within the `UITableView`

Answer (score 1):

you need to return at least 1 to be able to see some data

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 1):

Number of sections of tableView is 0! make it 1

Answer (score 1):

It may help you

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return 4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace your method this :

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
    #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    return 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That ist exactly what Apple's template meant by stating:

```
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
```

You need to return appropriate values there. 
Return 1 from `numberOfSectionsInTableView` if you just have 1 section (that ist the normal case I would say).
And return the number of rows that you want to be filled from `numberOfRowsInSection`. That may well be the count of an array or the number of fetched data sets or some hard coded value/constant value if it is not dynamic.

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` will then be called as maximum for each row/section combination that is possible but only for those cells that are visible from start or are about so be scrolled into visible areas.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
   //warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
   //   
  return 1;
}
```

---

As per this Datasource Method say that as number row require and you have to return 0 so not     generate any row so also not generate cell so as per our requirement static otherwise dynamic generate the row at least 1 row return.